# I'm having issue when updating table using triggers

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm using trigger to update the `monthly_sales` from the values of sales

**here is the code of triggers**

```
Update monthly_sales 
    SET sales =(SELECT SUM(sales.sales) FROM sales group by employee_id) ,
        comission =(SELECT SUM(sales.commsion) FROM sales group by employee_id)
 ;
```

**But this is giving me error**

> "SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more
>   than 1 row" .

Can anyone suggest what is the correct way to write this query?

Comment: In a trigger I would expect to see reference to NEW. and/or OLD. values.

Answer (score 0):

**avoid group by**

```
Update monthly_sales 
    SET sales =(SELECT SUM(sales.sales) FROM sales) ,
        comission =(SELECT SUM(sales.commsion) FROM sales);
```